# script in python to post on facebook - Graph API app type - architecture?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I use a rasperry pi to take pictures and want to make a python script to post them on an account on FB.
I created my app on the Grap API page of FB and I get a bit lost...

My app is neither on a server or an Android IOS app, so I don't have call back URL or so.

For Twitter and drop box, it's really straight forward, but FB ask me:

```
Image: Web Banner
Image: Cover Image
Image: Banner
You must upload at least 3 screenshots for Website with Facebook Login
Privacy Policy URL and more...
```

do I have to fulfill all these requirement just to post on facebook ?
Would it be better if I put a server with a domain name in between my raspberry pi and facebook to interact ? (or is it possible without ?)

I've tried to read the FB documentation. It's unreadable, unless you already know how it works, I guess.

I'm a noob on social media, but I'm a skilled engineer in embedded industrial systems, lost now...

If someone could give me some guidelines to start in the correct direction (kick start :) ), it would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance,
Mat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don´t need to fill in all those details. Only if you want to make your App public in the App Center. If you implement login, you need to fill in a Privacy Policy URL though.

The most important settings are in the "Settings" tab.

Here are some links you need to read for what you want to achieve:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.2
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed